# In Jquery, can i get the element back after removing?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using clone function to get deep copy then remove the briaid(text box) when usertype admin is selected, for rest usertype selection i want to get back the briaid but i am unable to do it.

**Note:** I know i can create the element(briaid) again but i want to know that is this possible by clone function.

```
<form id="user_login" method="POST">       
<select name="role_id" id="acc_type" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <option value="" selected="">Select Account Type</option>       
    <option value="100" >Admin</option>
    <option value="200">Agent</option>
    <option value="300">Technician</option>
    <option value="400">Support</option>
    <option value="500">Email</option>

</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user_code">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<div id="clone_my_element">
    <input type="number" id="briaId" placeholder="Bria ID" name="briaId" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-large btn-success btn-login" type="submit" >Login</button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
  $("#acc_type").change(function () {
   var elementclone = $("#clone_my_element").clone(true);
    if($(this).val() == "100"){ //if admin
      $("#clone_my_element").remove();
    }
    else{
         $("#clone_my_element").remove();
         $("#clone_my_element").append(elementclone); //not works
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `remove()` function will give out the element after removal so that you can reuse it, so just assign it to a temporary variable. Something like this:

```js
$(function () {
  var a = null;
  $(".rem").click(function () {
    a = $(".remove").remove();
  });
  $(".rea").click(function () {
    a.prependTo("body");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remove">This will be removed and readded.</div>
<button class="rem">Remove It</button>
<button class="rea">Readd Back</button>
```

In case of deep copying, just use `clone(true, true)` and store it in the variable and use `remove()` on it.

Comment: @Avnishtiwary Can you try to make a [mcve] in JSBin and share the link? I am unable to replicate the issue!

Comment: as i run your code snippet and hit the remove it button twice then clicking on Readd back has no any effect. Somehow my mistake was same. by the way thanks for catching the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is you are removing element (**clone_my_element**) and after that you are trying to append your cloned element to removed element (which is not exist in DOM). So, try to append cloned element at relevant place will solve your issue.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="clone_my_element">
    <input type="number" id="briaId" placeholder="Bria ID" name="briaId" required="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="6" oninput="this.value=this.value.slice(0,this.maxLength)">
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#clone_my_element").remove();
$("#container").append(elementclone);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `detach()` over `remove()`. Why?

`detach()` also removes the element **BUT** it keeps all assigned events and information. So when you reuse it and the item has an `event` assigned, the `event` will still work after reinserting.

Here is the fiddle:

```js
$(function () {
  var a = null;
  $(".rem").click(function () {
    a = $(".remove").detach();
  });
  $(".rea").click(function () {
    a.prependTo("body");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remove">This will be removed and readded.</div>
<button class="rem">Remove It</button>
<button class="rea">Readd Back</button>
```